# Why is neural network output in float instead of integers?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

i just finished a tutorial on how to build a neural net. Now i am trying to build a cost-sensitive neural net for binary classification. But somehow when i use the predict function my output is not binray, but float. I think i am doing something wrong but I dont know what.

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
cost_sensitive_NN = Sequential()
cost_sensitive_NN.add(Dense(12, activation = 'relu', input_dim=X_train_NN.shape[1]))
cost_sensitive_NN.add(Dropout(0.75))
cost_sensitive_NN.add(Dense(8, activation = 'relu'))
cost_sensitive_NN.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
cost_sensitive_NN.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'adam',metrics = ['AUC'])
cost_sensitive_NN.fit(X_train_NN, y_train_NN, class_weight = {0:1, 1:100}, epochs = 1)
```

Comment: This is expected behavior; the outputs represent the *probabilities* of your 2 classes, hence they should be indeed floats and not integers.

Comment: @desertnaut Careful, only in some cases do the outputs represent probabilities, and even then they are rarely true to what they should be. https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04599

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren agree, going into calibration issues and the details of the representation was not my intention here (neither it is a *programming*) topic.

Answer (score 2):

The `binary` in binary classification doesn't literally mean that your model will output a binary value.

Your final layer in the neural network is a [Dense layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense) with output shape `1`. The default type of the Dense layer output is float (and in fact [it can only be a floating point dtype](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2c48a3b38b6b6139be2da501982fd2f61d7d48fe/keras/layers/core/dense.py#L133). By training this model with a `binary_crossentropy` loss, we are teaching the model to output a float between `0.0` and `1.0` indicating the probability of the model input belonging to the positive class.

If you want a binary output like `0` or `1` during inference, you could set a probability threshold and return the appropriate binary value like so:

```py
def binary_inference(input_list, threshold=0.8):
    probability_list = cost_sensitive_NN(input_list)
    return probability_list >= threshold
```

Deciding on a threshold however, is a [whole other topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers).

Comment: instead of a list comprehension, one can use a vectorized approach: `output >= threshold` will give you a boolean array.

Comment: @jakub edited accordingly